# Récollement of stable $t$-structures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

Given a [recollement](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/recollement)
$$
\mathbf{D}^0  \underset{\underset{i_R}\leftarrow}{\overset{\overset{i_L}\leftarrow}\to} \mathbf{D} \underset{\underset{q_R}\leftarrow}{\overset{\overset{q_L}\leftarrow}\to} \mathbf{D}^1
$$
the machinery exposed in BBD's *Faisceaux Pervers* (Astérisque 100), and in a more modern language in

> Banagl, Markus. Topological invariants of stratified spaces. Springer Science & Business Media, 2007.

provides one with a $t$-structure on $\mathbf D$ obtained by "gluing *par recollement*" a $t$-structure $(\mathcal{D}_\ge^0, \mathcal{D}_\le^0)$ on $\mathbf D_0$ and a $t$-structure $(\mathcal{D}_\ge^1, \mathcal{D}_\le^1)$ on $\mathbf D_1$.

A *stable* $t$-structure is such that its classes are closed under shifts in both directions.

What happens when I glue two stable $t$-structures *par recollement*? It seems to me that the result is again stable. Can you provide a reference for this statement, if any, and applications of it to "concrete" situations? Does the theory of stratified spaces, or algebraic perverse sheaves, provide such an application, somewhere?

Note: [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200042/r%C3%A9collement-of-multiple-t-structures) question is motivated by the same interest.

Comment: This is recollement, not récollement. :-)

Comment: Look at Appendix E5 in http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bruno.kahn/preprints/der1mot.pdf

Comment: And certainly the result follows immediately from the "formula" for the glued t-structure.