# Recollement of multiple $t$-structures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

Given a [recollement](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/recollement)
$$
\mathbf{D}^0  \underset{\underset{i_R}\leftarrow}{\overset{\overset{i_L}\leftarrow}\to} \mathbf{D} \underset{\underset{q_R}\leftarrow}{\overset{\overset{q_L}\leftarrow}\to} \mathbf{D}^1
$$
the machinery exposed in BBD's *Faisceaux Pervers* (Astérisque 100), and in a more modern language in

> Banagl, Markus. Topological invariants of stratified spaces. Springer Science & Business Media, 2007.

provides one with a $t$-structure on $\mathbf D$ obtained by "gluing *par recollement*" a $t$-structure $(\mathcal{D}_\ge^0, \mathcal{D}_<^0)$ on $\mathbf D^0$ and a $t$-structure $(\mathcal{D}_\ge^1, \mathcal{D}_<^1)$ on $\mathbf D^1$.

**Edit**: Apparently this construction deserves a more detailed explanation. When you have a t-structure $\mathcal{D}^i_{\ge}$ (identified with its left aisle) on $\mathbf{D}^i$ you can define the gluing 
$$
(\mathcal{D}^0_\ge\wr\mathcal{D}_\ge^1, \mathcal{D}^0_<\wr\mathcal{D}_<^1)
$$
exploiting the functors $(i_L\dashv i\dashv i_R), (q_L\dashv q\dashv q_R)$: define
$$\begin{gather}
\{ X\in\mathbf{D}\mid qX\in \mathcal{D}_\ge^1, \; i_L X \in\mathcal{D}_\ge^0\}\\
\{ Y\in\mathbf{D}\mid qY \in\mathcal{D}_<^1,\; i_R Y \in\mathcal{D}_<^0 \}
\end{gather}$$
It can be shown that these two classes form a new t-structure.

Now, [BBD] and Banagl book, starting from the classical geometric example of a [stratification](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stratified+space) $\varnothing\subset U\subset X$ for a topological space, both insist on the fact that

> By applying the gluing Theorem [i.e. the construction providing the glued $t$-structure] inductively, the notion of a p-perverse t-structure quickly generalizes to spaces with more than two strata

The possibility of doing this ultimately relies into the fact that gluing *par recollement* is an associative operation, namely (in some sense to be specified) if we denote the [left aisle of the] glued $t$-structure above as $\mathcal{D}^0_\ge\wr\mathcal{D}_\ge^1$, we have
$$
(\mathcal{D}^0_\ge\wr\mathcal{D}_\ge^1)\wr \mathcal{D}^2_\ge = \mathcal{D}^0_\ge\wr(\mathcal{D}_\ge^1\wr \mathcal{D}^2_\ge).
$$
 In the geometric setting, I expect this result ultimately depend on the commutation of some diagrams of adjoint functors. Namely, the diagram

[image]

is commutative (in an obvious sense), where a squiggly arrow $f\colon \mathbf{D}\to \mathbf{D}'$ denotes a triple of adjoints $(f_L\dashv f\dashv f_R)$. In the geometric case, these maps are direct/inverse images, and the presence of a stratification $\varnothing U\subset V\subset X$ gives the desired compatibility.

Now,

> What happens in the general setting of an "abstract" recollement in a generic triangulated (or better, stable) category? Is there any property of recollements ensuring that the glued $t$-structure $\mathcal{D}_0 \wr\dots \wr \mathcal{D}_n$ exists in a definite sense?

Note: [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200040/r%C3%A9collement-of-stable-t-structures) question is motivated by the same interest.

Comment: Could you explain what gluing data do you have for your $D_i$? My guess it that $D_i$ should have "well-defined images" in the "glued category" $D$.

Comment: The gluing arises as the classical construction described for example in Banagl's book. You have a recollement like the one above, $t$-structures $t_i$ on $\mathbf D_i$ and you define $\mathcal D_{\ge 0}^0\wr \mathcal{D}_{\ge 0}^1$ as $\{X\in\mathbf{D}\mid q(X)\in \mathcal{D}_{\ge 0}^1,\; i_L(X)\in \mathcal{D}_{\ge 0}^0\}$. Dually, $\mathcal D_{\le 0}^0\wr \mathcal{D}_{\le 0}^1 = (\mathcal D_{\ge 0}^0\wr \mathcal{D}_{\ge 0}^1)^\perp = \{Y\in\mathbf{D}\mid q(Y)\in \mathcal{D}_{\le 0}^1,\; i_R(X)\in \mathcal{D}_{\le 0}^0\}$.

Comment: [continued] Part of the problem is to establish, in the general case, what is the structure needed for the iterated gluing to make sense. Being the exposition (again in Banagl book) conducted in the full generality of triangulated categories, and since there is no mention of particular properties asked to the various $D_i$... I would expect (and I hope) the result is true in abstract situations, more general than the geometric case. What do you think?

Comment: Definitely no geometry is necessary here; yet could you describe the setting you consider in more detail?

Comment: Sure. What is precisely the clarification you need? The geometric case suggests that for three $t$-structures $\mathcal{D}_\ge^i$, $i=0,1,2$ like above you need *four* distinct (but "compatible" in a sense) recollements. I can expand on this, if it's what you mean

Comment: I cannot give an answer until I know which functors and triangulated categories you consider.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here :) I'm not asking whether it is possible to glue multiple t-structures in a particular situation. Instead, I'm asking what are the assumptions making the gluing possible, given that the mere specification of recollements on a single piece is not enough to ensure the existence of the glued structure. I can expand on the case of three pieces; but I have no idea about the general case, since in the gluing of $n$ t-structures you have to take into account *more* than $n$ recollements.

Comment: Now that this has been clarified, the answer to your question should be: take $n$ triangulated categories with $n$ distinct $t$-structures on them, specified, say, by $n$ left aisles $\mathcal{D}_{\ge 0}^i$; how many recollements do I have to specify, and how they must be arranged, in order to turn the gluing $\mathcal{D}_{\ge 0}^0\wr \dots\wr \mathcal{D}_{\ge 0}^n$ into a well-defined t-structure?

Comment: No, this was not clarified clearly enough for me to understand it. For which triangulated categories do you consider this "multiple glued" t-structures?

Comment: It could be my fault, but I'm not able to understand what are you asking for. We should discuss this issue in a private conversation. I suspect the mutual understanding is ruined by the delay between two consecutive answers...

Comment: I slightly expanded the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check that thoroughfully, but it seems that in the ("abstract") setting you are interested in there exist (exact) "projections" $j^{i*}:D\to D^i$ and $j^{i!}:D\to D^i$ ($D$ is the "big" triangulated category). Then the halves of the "glued $t$-structure" for $D$ are given by the following formulas:  $D^{\le 0}=\{M\in  Obj D:\ j^{i*}M\in D^{i, \le 0}\forall i\}$, $D^{\ge 0}=\{M\in  Obj D:\ j^{!*}M\in D^{i, \ge 0}\forall i\}$. This certainly does not depend on the order on the gluing.